# Selenium getText() compatible textContent in puppeteer?

Tags: selenium, puppeteer

In selenium, [getText()](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-element-text) returns [normalised text](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e09e28f016c9f53196cf68d6f71991c5af4a35d4/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L981).  In the following case, it returns `Unit Tests 15`

```
<div test-id="something">
  <div>Unit Tests</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
```

I am in the process of converting 1000s of lines of test code from selenium to puppeteer, and comparing `something.textContent` with `Unit Tests 15` is failing because `textContent` returns `Unit Tests15` not `Unit Tests 15`.

So I am looking to emulate selenium's getText() in puppeteer.  Is there anything that currently does this?

I think my options are:

- remove space, then compare (not ideal)
- implement getVisibleText inside the page.evaluate() callback (inefficient)
- another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final version of a workaround I have implemented which emulates getText() as best I can. It may not be 100% but it works well enough for my existing tests.

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.evaluate(`
  window.dalang = {
    _isBlock: function(el) {
      var display = getComputedStyle(el).display;
      if (display) {
        switch (display) {
          case "block": return true;
          case "inherit": break;
          default: return false;
        }
      }
      switch(node.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "span": case "b": case "i":
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    getVisibleText: function(el) {
      var text = '', s, cns = el.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < cns.length; i++) {
        var node = cns[i];
        var sep = ' ';
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {
          switch(node.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
          case "style": case "script": break;
          default:
            s = this.getVisibleText(node);
            if (this._isBlock(node)) sep = '\\n';
            break;
          }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
          s = node.textContent;
        } else {
          s = '';
        }
        s = s.replace(/[\\n]+/g,'\\n').replace(/^[ \\t\\n]+|[ \\t\\n]+$/,'');   // trim only soft space
        if (s) {
          text = (text && text + sep) + s;
        }
      }
      return text.replace(String.fromCharCode(160),' ');
    },
  };
`);
```

Then later when I want to get text to compare to my test values...

```
await page.evaluate(el => dalang.getVisibleText(el), element)
```

Answer (score 0):

[html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text) looks like a solution for you. Here is the implementation of your problem with this package:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { fromString } = require('html-to-text');

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <div test-id="something">
      <div>Unit Tests</div>
      <div>15</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const somethingToTest = await page.$('[test-id="something"]');

  const pureText = fromString(
    await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, somethingToTest)
  );

  console.log(pureText); // Unit Tests 15

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, nice little utility, but it needs to be compatible with selenium's getText() which html-to-text isn't.